# How to vertically grow and shrink menu (with animation)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I mimmick the effect that is used for the Contents list on Wikipedia pages when I click on the show/hide toggle? I also want the toggle to go next to the 'Contents' title but it's not working.

```css
.contents_list {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1.25;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
.toggle {
  display: inline;
}
.contents_list h3 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #000;
}
.contents_list a {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
}
.contents_list ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
.contents_list li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents_list">
  <h2>Contents</h2><span class="toggle">&nbsp;[<a role="button" tabindex="0" id="togglelink">show</a>]&nbsp;</span>
  <ol>
    <li><a>A1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>A2</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first option you can use JQuery toggle function `toggle()`

And for the second option use `html bookmarks`, give `ID` to section and then use that `ID` in `a` tag to navigate.

```js
$('#togglelink').click(function() {
  $('ol').toggle(300);
  if ($(this).text() == "show")
    $(this).text("hide")
  else
    $(this).text("show");
})
```

```css
.contents_list {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1.25;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
.toggle {
  display: inline;
}
.contents_list h3 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #000;
}
.contents_list a {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
}
.contents_list ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
.contents_list li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
h2{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents_list">
  <h2>Contents</h2><span class="toggle">&nbsp;[<a role="button" tabindex="0" id="togglelink">hide</a>]&nbsp;</span>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#firstBookmark">A1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#secondBookmark">A2</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div id="firstBookmark">
  <h1>A1</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum
  dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.
</div>
<div id="secondBookmark">
  <h1>A2</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda ipsa, quis ipsum
  dolor, numquam sint quasi. Culpa mollitia voluptatum nisi, libero, perferendis fugiat laboriosam enim iusto accusantium rem quam pariatur.
</div>
```

Comment: I need the word 'show' to change to 'hide' when I click it & vice versa + the animation too. I also need to toggle to appear next to the 'Contents' title. Please edit your answer as appropriate.

Comment: Updated my answer, check again @MacaronLover

Comment: What does `300` mean in `$('ol').toggle(300);`?

Comment: Its a duration of toggle, that is creating animation effect, 300 is 300 mili seconds... For more info http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp